# Getting button visible on long click of recycler view item

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview

Hi guys I have a case here. I have an activity inside which there is a recycler view. The recycler view contains cardview as items. There are two buttons on the activity i.e. delete and cancel.

Here what I want is that on long click of cardview item of recycler view the delete and cancel button should appear. Also, I should be able to proforma delete by clicking the delete button (i.e. remove the item from recycle view) while cancel button will just remove the selection from the cardview.

What is the approach should I follow. I can implement onLongClick listener inside adapter class of recycler view but how to make button visible.

Please help.

Comment: Make the activity listen to `onLongClick` by implementing a custom listener to the adapter

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach in Adapter onBindViewHolder

```
listview.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int position, long id) {
               
               
new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
.setTitle("Delete entry")
.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this entry?")

.setPositiveButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
        
        list.remove(position);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
 })

// A null listener allows the button to dismiss the dialog and take no further action.
.setNegativeButton("cancel", null)
.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
.show();


                return true; 
            }
        });
```

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted by will work that way also.

Answer (score 0):

We can use Interface to communicate the click listener, between the activity and view holder.

**Interface**

```
interface IRecyclerViewListener {
    void onItemClick(int position);
}
```

**Activity**

```
class RecyclerActivty implements IRecyclerViewListener {

//This is user defined method...
public void setADapter() {
RecyclerAdapter adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(this);
recyclerview.setAdapter(adapter);
}

   public  void onItemClick(int position) {
   //Handle the button visibility here...
}
}
```

**RecyclerAdapter**

```
class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {

private IRecyclerViewListener iRecyclerViewListener = null;

public RecyclerAdapter (IRecyclerViewListener iRecyclerViewListener) {
  this.iRecyclerViewListener = iRecyclerViewListener;
}

}
```

Now the interface object has been passed to adapter, from their we can pass to viewholder same way via constructor. In View holder inside the view click listener write **iRecyclerViewListener.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition());**. This way we can communicate from adapter to activity.